# migrating to d3 v4 cause duplicates on drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am migrating this project https://bl.ocks.org/cjrd/6863459 to d3 v4  https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#dragging-d3-drag

**JSFIDDLE** https://jsfiddle.net/9wwqgwhh/1/

Canvas is rendering, but there is some kind of problem with dragging. 
I have to change this code.

```
  GraphCreator.prototype.dragmove = function(d) {
    var thisGraph = this;
    if (thisGraph.state.shiftNodeDrag){
      thisGraph.dragLine.attr('d', 'M' + d.x + ',' + d.y + 'L' + d3.mouse(thisGraph.svgG.node())[0] + ',' + d3.mouse(this.svgG.node())[1]);
    } else{
      d.x += d3.event.dx;
      d.y +=  d3.event.dy;
      thisGraph.updateGraph();
    }
```

};
Somehow thisGraph.updateGraph(); causing infinite node ceation on dragging, but it's all that I could find out.

This is a updateGraph function

> // call to propagate changes to graph
>   GraphCreator.prototype.updateGraph = function(){
>
> ```
> var thisGraph = this,
>     consts = thisGraph.consts,
>     state = thisGraph.state;
>
> thisGraph.paths = thisGraph.paths.data(thisGraph.edges, function(d){
>   return String(d.source.id) + "+" + String(d.target.id);
> });
> var paths = thisGraph.paths;
> // update existing paths
> paths.style('marker-end', 'url(#end-arrow)')
>   .classed(consts.selectedClass, function(d){
>     return d === state.selectedEdge;
>   })
>   .attr("d", function(d){
>     return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "L" + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
>   });
>
> // add new paths
> paths.enter()
>   .append("path")
>   .style('marker-end','url(#end-arrow)')
>   .classed("link", true)
>   .attr("d", function(d){
>     return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "L" + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
>   })
>   .on("mousedown", function(d){
>     thisGraph.pathMouseDown.call(thisGraph, d3.select(this), d);
>     }
>   )
>   .on("mouseup", function(d){
>     state.mouseDownLink = null;
>   });
> ```

Comment: have you checked out what `thisGraph.updateGrapth();` does?

Comment: I guess it's where is a roblem, but I can't find d3 v4 changes for this part. added thisGraph.updateGrapth in question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `updateGraph()` replace the lines

```
newGs.append("circle")
  .attr("r", String(consts.nodeRadius));

newGs.each(function(d){
  thisGraph.insertTitleLinebreaks(d3.select(this), d.title);
});
```

with these

```
newGs.each(function(d) {
  if (this.childNodes.length === 0) {
    d3.select(this)
      .append("circle")
      .attr("r", String(consts.nodeRadius));
    thisGraph.insertTitleLinebreaks(d3.select(this), d.title);
  }
});
```

Tested with d3 up to version 5.7